# Uk visitors visa refusal third time

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, serial-refusals

[image: page1][image: page2]
I have submitted all proof including CA certificate for fund into my parent's bank account. 
Fund in my parent's account was deposited by me two years ago and I have provided proof in second application. They mentioned in first rejection letter about this fund.
The proof of funds in my brother and sister in law’s account was explained in the letter and supported by tax return. 
I am planning for JRS.

Comment: It is not about having funds, but the origin of the funds ("parents" is not enough, you need to proof that your parents money are not money parking and they can afford to give you such money) -- after your edit: check about "money parking" which is always bad sign

Comment: They think you present an unacceptably high immigration risk. Signs of ‘funds parking’ in the bank statements, a long visit, presumably/possibly lack of strong ties to India, family in UK, all red flags pointing towards a potential overstay. See eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e